# Проверка записи в MYSQL перед INSERT в файле node.js

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, web-scraping

Вот часть кода. Я новичек и у меня два вопроса.

```
 let [phones, computers, numbers, accessories, smartwatches] = cat;
let names = ["phones", "computers", "numbers", "accessories", "smartwatches"];
let exist = "SELECT url FROM categories";
let sql = "INSERT INTO `categories` (`name`, `url`) VALUES ('"+names+"', '"+url+"')";
if(exist == false){
  connection.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
    console.log("Records inserted");
  });
}
else{
  break;
};
```

Правильно ли так писать и плюс

```
 let [phones, computers, numbers, accessories, smartwatches] = cat;
let names = ["phones", "computers", "numbers", "accessories", "smartwatches"];
let sql = "INSERT INTO `categories` (`name`, `url`) VALUES ('"+names+"', '"+url+"')";
  connection.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
    console.log("Records inserted");
  });
```

сначала код был таким. Я после Values names и url писал без ковычек и просто в одних ковычках но код не работал. Но потом случайно так попробовал и получилось. Мне интересно почему?

Comment: 1. Вы можете сделать поле url уникальным в таблице и использовать `insert ignore into ...` что бы вставить запись только если такой еще нет. 2. Синтаксис SQL требует что бы текстовые значения были в кавычках, поэтому без них и не работает. 3. Но писать так _нельзя_, надо использовать плейсхолдеры в тексте запроса и передавать переменные для них отдельно. посмотрите примеры например тут http://stepansuvorov.com/blog/2012/09/node-js-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-mysql/  В том виде, как у вас сейчас, если кто то случайно (или намеренно) вставит кавычки в url ваш запрос не сработает

Comment: спасибо большое за ответ! Посмотрю сейчас примеры.